# Unicorn has undefined method error ONLY in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, ancestry

My app is working great in development mode AND production using WEBrick.
But in Unicorn, it only works in development mode. As soon as I try to edit or update a category I get a no method error. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

### Error:

```
Started GET "/symbols/smoke" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-17 08:06:02 -0700
Processing by CategoriesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"smoke"}
  Rendered layouts/_tabs.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered categories/_meanings.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered categories/_categorylist.html.haml (2.5ms)
  Rendered categories/_show-page.html.haml (13.5ms)
  Rendered categories/show.js.erb (17.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
    3:      %li.nav-header a parent of:
    4:      - if @category.has_children?
    5:          
    6:          = list_categories(@children)
    7:      %li
    8:          = link_to new_category_path(:parent_id => @category, :view => "show"), :remote => true do
    9:              Add Child
  app/helpers/categories_helper.rb:21:in `list_categories'
  app/views/categories/_categorylist.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_categories__categorylist_html_haml__3404053025802473956_70332682747260'
  app/views/categories/_show-page.html.haml:48:in `_app_views_categories__show_page_html_haml__1783905832676874426_70332684530780'
  app/views/categories/show.js.erb:8:in `_app_views_categories_show_js_erb___3948970986596034947_70332684487680'
  app/controllers/old_categories.rb:96:in `show'
```

### Categories Controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  helper :lego
  helper :meanings

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    if params[:id]
      @categories = Category.find(params[:id])                      #if params[:id]
      @categories = @categories.children.arrange(:order => 'name')
    elsif params[:view] == "alpha"
      @alphabet   = Category.all.group_by{|c| c.name[0]}
      @see_kids   = false
      @categories = @categories.sort(:name => "ASC")                            if !params[:letter]
      @categories = @categories.where(name: eval("/^#{params[:letter]}/i")).sort(:name => "ASC")     if params[:letter]
    else
      # @categories = Category.all
      @categories = @categories.arrange(:order => 'name')               #if params[:view] != "list"
    end



    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end

  def reorder
    if Rails.env != "production" && !request.xhr?
      flash[:info] = "Currently in #{Rails.env} mode."
    end
    @categories = Category.arrange(:order => 'name')
    @new = Category.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
    @next = Category.count
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end

  def sort
    params[:category].each do |id, attr|
      thisCat = params[:category][id]
      @category = Category.where(:_id => id).first
      if thisCat.nil? || thisCat == 'null'
        @category.parent_id = nil
        @category.name_tag  = @category.name
      else
        @category.parent_id = thisCat.to_s
        @category.name_tag = "#{@category.name} <small>(#{@category.parent.name})</small>"
      end
      @category.save
    end
  end

  def gallery
    @categories = Category.arrange(:order => 'name')
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @siblings = Category.siblings_of(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
  end

   def show
     @category    = Category.find(params[:id])
     @updater     = User.find(@category.user) || nil
     get_meanings(@category)
     # @meanings    = @category.meanings 

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.js
       format.json { render json: @category }
     end
   end

  def search
    @categories = Category.arrange(:order => 'name')
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    @meanings = @category.meanings
    @meanings = @meanings.where(:beliefs => params[:beliefs])         if params[:beliefs]
    @meanings = @meanings.where(:cultures => params[:cultures])       if params[:cultures]
    @meanings = @meanings.where(:connotation => params[:connotation]) if params[:connotation]
    @meanings = @meanings.where(:user => params[:user])               if params[:user]    
  end

  def new
    @new = Category.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
    @form_state   = "new"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json
    end
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json
    end
  end

  def create
    @new          = Category.new(params[:category])
    @new.user     = current_user
    @new.name_tag = @new.name
    @new.name_tag = "#{@new.name} <small>#{@new.parent.name}</small>"       if @new.parent

    respond_to do |format|
      if @new.save
        get_meanings(@new)
        flash[:success] = "<h4><i class=icon-ok></i> '#{@new.name}' was successfully created.</h4>"
        format.html { redirect_to @new }
        if session[:form_type] == "show"
          format.js {redirect_to @new }
        else
          format.js
        end
        format.json { render json: @categories, status: :created, location: @new }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js 
        format.json { render json: @new.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @categories  = Category.arrange(:order => 'name')
    @category           = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.user      = current_user 
    @category.name_tag  = params[:category][:name]
    # @siblings           = Category.siblings_of(params[:id])
    @category.name_tag  = "#{params[:category][:name]} <small>#{@category.parent.name}</small>"       if @category.parent
    params[:view]       = "reorder"           if session[:form_type] == "reorder"

    flash[:success] = "<h4><i class=icon-ok></i> #{@category.name} was successfully updated.</h4>"
    get_meanings(@category)
    respond_to do |format|
      # get_meanings(@category)
      # @similar     = Category.where(:name => params[:category][:name])
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html { redirect_to @category}
        if session[:form_type] == "show"
          format.js #{redirect_to @category }
        else
          format.js 
        end
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        # get_meanings(@category)
        flash[:error] = "<h4>Unable to update #{@category.name}</h4>"
        format.html { render action: "edit", error: "Unable to update '#{@category.name}'", status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    flash[:alert] = "<h4><i class=icon-warning-sign></i> Warning. You have deleted the category '#{@category.name}'.</h4>".html_safe
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js 
    end
  end

  def has_sidebar?
    self.has_children?
  end
private
  def get_meanings(category)
    @categories  = Category.arrange(:order => 'name')
    @children    = category.children.order_by(name: :asc) || []
    @siblings    = category.siblings.order_by(name: :asc) || []
    @similar     = Category.where(:name => category.name) || []
    @meanings    = category.meanings 
    @belief_list    = []
    @culture_list   = []
    @contributors   = []
    @connotations   = []
    for meaning in @meanings
      for belief in meaning.beliefs
        @belief_list << belief 
      end
      for culture in meaning.cultures
        @culture_list << culture
      end
      @connotations << meaning.connotation
      @contributors << meaning.user
    end
    @beliefs      = @belief_list.uniq
    @cultures     = @culture_list.uniq
    @contributors = @contributors.uniq
    @connotations = @connotations.uniq
  end
end
```

### Show Page:

```
.row
    .span12
        = breadcrumb(@category)
.row
    %section.span10.pull-right
        .row
            %header.span10
                .hero-unit.relative
                    .row
                        - if @category.image?
                            %figure.span3
                                = image_tag @category.image_url

                        .span5
                            %h1
                                = raw @category.name_tag

                            %p= @category.description
                            - if @similar.any?
                                - unless @similar.first.id == @category.id && @similar.last.id == @category.id


                                    See also: 

                                -@similar.each do |ref|
                                    -unless ref.id == @category.id
                                        = link_to raw(ref.name_tag), ref, :remote => true

                            -if @updater
                                .updated-by
                                    Last updated by 
                                    = @updater.name

        .row
            .span10.no-history
                #meaning-controls.row
                    .span2
                        = link_to [:new, @category, :meaning], :class => "btn", remote: true do
                            Add Meaning
                            %i.icon-plus
                    - if @meanings.any?
                        = render 'sorting-hat'
                #meanings.no-history
                    -if @meanings
                        = render 'meanings'

    %aside.span2.float-desktop
        = render 'categorylist'
```

### Helper:

```
  def list_categories(categories) 
      categories.map do |category|
        content_tag(:li) do
          link_to h(category.name), category, :remote => true
        end
      end.join.html_safe
  end
```

## Update:

Searched through my `production.rb` file going line by line and found that the line that brings about this error is `config.cache_classes = false`. As soon as I set it to `true` it saves normally. Any ideas why this would cause the error?

Comment: Silly question. Does your gemfile have all the gems you require under production?

Comment: Actually I was having a problem with that previously, so right now ALL gems are available in EVERY environment. So there's NO gem that is only available in development mode or anything. **Not ideal, I know.** Haven't gotten around to fixing that. Should I post that too?

Comment: FYI: the error happens in show.js.erb, more specifically categories/_categorylist.html.haml. The instance variable @children is nil when you expect it to be an array. You define it in `get_meanings`, check if it executes at all (use `logger.debug` there).

Comment: TRying to read up on logging to accomplish that now...

Comment: When I change to `config.cache_classes = true`, even in development mode, I don't see any logger.debug messages anymore. I've added log messages to the edit and update actions which work when it's turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned off `config.cache_classes` for the time being. The problem has something to do with me not expiring my caches properly. I will figure it out and address it after focusing on cleaning up and re-factoring my code a bit.

I will update this answer after I start focusing again on caching.